# Validate two textbox Greater than

Tags: javascript, ajax

how i will automatic validate when i put value on quantitytotransfer using ajax or javascript the two textbox it should not greater than the
quantity on hand the value of quantitytotransfer ?

```
     <input type="number"
            class="form-control"
            readonly
            name="quantityonhand"
            id="quantityonhand">

    <input type="number"
           required
           class="form-control"
           name="quantitytotransfer"
           id="quantitytotransfer"
           maxlength="11"
           onkeypress="return isNumber(event);"
           required>

function verify() {                       
  var n = $("#quanitytotransfer").val();                       
  if (n => $( "#quanityonhand" ).val())                                              
  {
    alert("greater than quantity on hand");       
  }                                                        
  else                                                     
  {                                                        
    alert("greater than quantity on hand");       
}                                                                                              

</script>
```

Comment: somebody have any idea?

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle

Comment: i already put my jquery codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use parseInt to check if one value is greater than the other. also, you need to bind this function to the input

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#quantitytotransfer").on("input", function() {
    verify()
  });
});

function verify() {
  var firstValue = parseInt($("#quantitytotransfer").val());
  var secondValue = parseInt($("#quantityonhand").val());
  if (firstValue >= secondValue) {
    alert("greater or equal than quantity on hand");
  } else {
    alert("smaller than quantity on hand");
  }
}  
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shirandror/5w9a0o6e/

Comment: how will i validate this once quantitytotransfer have inputed the value ? onchange?

Comment: on input deals also with paste (ctrl+v or via mouse). The first script will bind the verify() function to any change in #quantitytotransfer element

Comment: can you put in fiddle?

Comment: its work however how will blank the textbox after it alert?

Comment: you can do this $("#quantitytotransfer").val("") to empty the input box